# Print paragraph if it contains a string stored in a variable (blank lines separate paragraphs)

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to isolate the header of a mail in the /var/spool/mail/mysuser file.

Print a paragraph if it contains AAA (blank lines separate paragraphs)

sed is working when searching with the string "AAA"

```
$ sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/AAA/!d;' /var/spool/mail/mysuser
```

When using a variable is does not work :

```
$ MyVar="AAA"
$ sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/$MyVar/!d;' /var/spool/mail/mysuser
```

=> No output as the single quotes prevent the expantion of the variable

Trying with singles quotes

```
$ sed -e "/./{H;$!d;}" -e "x;/$MyVar/!d; /var/spool/mail/mysuser
sed: -e expression #2, char 27: extra characters after command
```

Actually, the first search is also not working with doubles quotes

```
$ sed -e "/./{H;$!d;}" -e 'x;/AAA/!d;" /var/spool/mail/mysuser
sed -e "/./{H;$!d;}" -e "x;/AAA/date;" /var/spool/mail/mysuser
sed: -e expression #2, char 9: extra characters after command
```

I am also considering awk without success so far

Any advices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because of the single quotes. You need to go out of the single quotes to enable interpolation:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/'$MyVar'/!d;' /var/spool/mail/mysuser
```

or, better put the variable in double quotes:

```
sed -e '/./{H;$!d;}' -e 'x;/'"$MyVar"'/!d;' /var/spool/mail/mysuser
```

Comment: Many thanks, exactly the expected outcome, the awk solution is fine for me too!

Answer (score 4):

should be trivial with `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS= '/AAA/' file
```

with a variable, little more needed

```
$ awk -v RS= -v var='AAA' '$0~var'
```

or if it's defined elsewhere

```
$ awk -v RS= -v var="$variable_holding_value" '$0~var'
```

Comment: Thanks, I do no read you full response, this is a clean solution !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to karakfa
It works with :

```
MyVar="AAA"
awk -v RS= -v X=$MyVar '$0~X' file
```

Comment: Double quote `"$MyVar"`, in case it includes spaces or special chars.